# Deities vs You /Liquid Anon/ What'd be the most optimal carrier fluid comopsition?

Tags: science-based, chemistry, materials, hydrodynamics

Liquid Anon is my little OC, a total badass, with the ability to assume any form and color at a whim. Donut steel!

> A magnetorheological fluid (MR fluid, or MRF) a type of smart fluid in a carrier fluid, usually a type of oil. When
>   subjected to a magnetic field, the fluid greatly increases its
>   apparent viscosity, to the point of becoming a viscoelastic solid.
>   Importantly, the yield stress of the fluid when in its active ("on")
>   state can be controlled very accurately by varying the magnetic field
>   intensity. The upshot is that the fluid's ability to transmit force
>   can be controlled with an electromagnet, which gives rise to its many
>   possible control-based applications.

The basic idea is that Anon's body is this [magnetorheological fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetorheological_fluid), but using nanomachines, son. These machines are in the micrometer range (100 micrometers) and are capable of generating their own magnetic fields. When in a field, the nanite can choose to block it out, or line up with it and generate another.

That's the basic concept, but ignoring the nanites, their carrier fluid has some... unanswered question in terms of composition.

### What does it have to accomplish?

1. **Nanites can be suspended in it:** I mean, that's why the magic happens!
2. **Magnetic permeability**: I don't know why, though **^^**
3. **Chemical stability:** Anon is 100% fireproof and resistant to acids and bases, except for that time when a *certain person* poured ClF3 all over him.
4. **Lightweight:** Anon already has battery problems and is dense enough, thanks to his nanites. The carrier fluid should add minimal weight.

Any bonus (maybe energy storage) function is appreciated, but not mandatory.

**Judgment process:** Objectives are ordered into priorities, the first (most important) is worth n points, the next is n/2, after that n/2^k, the highest score wins.

### Objectives:

- Everything in the "What does it have to accomplish?" ordered list, already in priority order as well.
- If there's something extra that gives an edge in combat and doesn't involve CLF3 or the Nuremberg trials

**What carrier fluid should I use, that meets these criteria?**

- Feel free to build the solution up from the molecular level.
- I went forward and addressed internal and external heating, with aerogels and a heat radiator.

**Note:** Though I could use nanomachines for everything, it's both more complicated and energy demanding than fluids, so it really is the last option.

Comment: I see this. I see nano-machines. Liquid Anon's powers come from the best kind of nano-machines. I see Jojo mentioned,all I can think now is about a Stand with nano-machines. Btw have a link for your OC or stories with him in it?

Comment: To VTCers, give proper reasoning.

Comment: *"This is because only the person who is developing a plotline can decide how characters will act or the plots will develop. Worldbuilding can determine **what is possible**, but the choices about what happens given those possibilities belong to the author."* So, how exactly is the chemical composition, based on already established properties, of my little deity's avatar is something he'd act or only I can decide?

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta] at [Why was the “Deities vs You /Liquid Anon/ What'd be the most optimal carrier fluid comopsition?” put on hold as too story-based?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7220/29)

Answer (score 4):

**Your nanites are the fluid.**

[image: faceted magnetic beads]
[https://www.amazon.com/Imagine-If-Hematite-Magnetic-Gorgeous/dp/B01FE2GI7W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FE2GI7W)

They are faceted, and can lock together on their facets.  They can roll across each other and produce whatever shape desired.  They are so small that functionally they themselves comprise a fluid, albeit a thixotropic fluid.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thixotropy

> Thixotropy is a time-dependent shear thinning property. Certain gels
>   or fluids that are thick, or viscous, under static conditions will
>   flow (become thin, less viscous) over time when shaken, agitated,
>   sheared or otherwise stressed (time dependent viscosity). They then take a fixed time to return to a more viscous state...
>    Both cytoplasm and the ground substance in the human body are thixotropic, as is
>   semen.